# PHP while-for nested loops not showing all MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I've looked through some of the other answers on this, but they don't seem to solve my particular issue (or I am coding them wrong, which is also possible).

I know my SQL code works right, as I get all 19 rows of output, but when I output it to a PHP page, the page shorts me by 5 rows.

If I don't try to show the results in three columns by whatever (and just use one column) everything shows.  When I try to do three by 'X', is when it starts cutting off results.

Here is my old, not working PHP code:

```
$fleet_query_results = @mysql_query($fleet_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fleet_query_results)) {
    $display_fleet .= "<tr>";

    for($i = 1; $i < 4 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($fleet_query_results); $i++) {
        $ship_info = $row['ship_info'];
        $mem_info = $row['mem_info'];
        $ship_link = $row['ship_link'];

        $display_fleet .= "
            <td valign=\"top\"><div id=\"fleet\"><div id=\"fheader\">$ship_info</div><br/><img align=\"center\" height=\"210\" width=\"350\" alt=\"$ship_name\" src=\"$ship_link\" /><br /><div id=\"fmem\">$mem_info</div></div></td>
        ";
    }

    $display_fleet .= "</tr>";
}
```

Any ideas?  It's cutting off the first, fourth, ninth, thirteenth and seventeenth results.

Example page results:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>Header<br />Image<br />People</td><td>Header<br />Image<br />People</td><td>Header<br />Image<br />People</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Header<br />Image<br />People</td><td>Header<br />Image<br />People</td><td>Header<br />Image<br />People</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Header<br />Image<br />People</td><td>Header<br />Image<br />People</td><td>Header<br />Image<br />People</td></tr>
</table>
```

New code that works, but is **UGLY**:

```
    $fleet_query_results = @mysql_query($fleet_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fleet_query_results)) {
    $display_fleet .= "<tr>";
    $ship_info = $row['ship_info'];
    $mem_info = $row['mem_info'];
    $ship_link = $row['ship_link'];

    $display_fleet .= "
        <td valign=\"top\"><div id=\"fleet\"><div id=\"fheader\">$ship_info</div><br/><img align=\"center\" height=\"210\" width=\"350\" alt=\"$ship_name\" src=\"$ship_link\" /><br /><div id=\"fmem\">$mem_info</div></div></td>
    ";

    for($i = 1; $i < 3 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($fleet_query_results); $i++) {
        $ship_info = $row['ship_info'];
        $mem_info = $row['mem_info'];
        $ship_link = $row['ship_link'];

        $display_fleet .= "
            <td valign=\"top\"><div id=\"fleet\"><div id=\"fheader\">$ship_info</div><br/><img align=\"center\" height=\"210\" width=\"350\" alt=\"$ship_name\" src=\"$ship_link\" /><br /><div id=\"fmem\">$mem_info</div></div></td>
        ";
    }

    $display_fleet .= "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: what does `$i < 4` mean in your loop?

Comment: __#1__ Stop supressing potential errors with `@`. __#2__ Stop using the old deprecated MySQL extension, and switch to MySQLi or PDO __#3__ Why are you fetching a result in your `while` loop, and again in your `for` loop?

Comment: you're fetching rows in outerloop, which are not displayed, this is why some rows are missing

Comment: @MarkBaker - Thanks for the heads up.  Didn't realize that it had been depreciated.  I am now working to retrofit my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` was eating some of the data rows.

```
$fleet_query_results = @mysql_query($fleet_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$rows=1;
while($rows) {
    $display_fleet .= "<tr>";

    for($i = 1; $i < 4 && $row = mysql_fetch_array($fleet_query_results); $i++) {
        $rows=$row;
        if (!$row) break;
        $ship_info = $row['ship_info'];
        $mem_info = $row['mem_info'];
        $ship_link = $row['ship_link'];

        $display_fleet .= "
            <td valign=\"top\"><div id=\"fleet\"><div id=\"fheader\">$ship_info</div><br/><img align=\"center\" height=\"210\" width=\"350\" alt=\"$ship_name\" src=\"$ship_link\" /><br /><div id=\"fmem\">$mem_info</div></div></td>
        ";
    }

    $display_fleet .= "</tr>";
}
```

or, as discussed below:

```
$i=0
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fleet_query_results)) {

    if( $i % 4 = 0 )
        $display_fleet .= "<tr>";

    $ship_info = $row['ship_info'];
    $mem_info = $row['mem_info'];
    $ship_link = $row['ship_link'];

    $display_fleet .= "
            <td valign=\"top\"><div id=\"fleet\"><div id=\"fheader\">$ship_info</div><br/><img align=\"center\" height=\"210\" width=\"350\" alt=\"$ship_name\" src=\"$ship_link\" /><br /><div id=\"fmem\">$mem_info</div></div></td>
        ";

    if( ++$i % 4 = 0 )
        $display_fleet .= "</tr>\n";

}

// clean add the missing cells to last row.
if( $i % 4 != 0 )
{
    while($i++ %4)
      $display_fleet .= "<td></td>";
    $display_fleet .= "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, but I suspect it would be cleaner to remove the inner loop entirely.

Comment: yeah, it;s a mess. As you say the inner loop needs re-tooling. The inner loop formats the data into 4 columns, the columns seem to be arbitrary, unless there's something special about the query. probably a better solution woild be to just use fixed-size divs with style `display:inline-block` and let the brouser organise them rows and columns.

Comment: Or using modulus (`%`) to work out when to finish a table row and start a new one.

Comment: I am just getting back into coding... haven't done it in years (and reusing my old code), so if you have better ways of doing it, I am open.  And I tried the modifications, but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: yeah, that sort of thing. I usually use a counter which I reset, but the same effect,

Comment: I did get it working, showing everything, but it is UGLY code.  Again, any better ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: @RussTeicheira have added an improved version, possibly with a few syntax errors, but I think you'll understand what is meant,

Comment: A few errors, but got it working!  Thanks!  Now for me to "play" with it to learn what it's doing.